# wordpress custom field content as popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a price stored in the custom field 'price'. clickbtn is class that gives it shape of button. I am trying to have only "click here to reveal price" text within the clickbtn...what I am trying to achieve is when the person clicks on the clickbtn **a popup comes which should hold the content of the 'price'** as well as open the link www.bookurl.com in a new tab.

```
<div class="clickbtn">
   <a href="http://www.bookurl.com">
      <?php echo get_field('price');?> Click Here to reveal price
   <a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use javascript for this, not PHP as tagged.

The simplest way, with simple JS :

```
<span id="price" style="display:none"><?php echo get_field('price');?></span>
<a id="price_ad" href="http://www.bookurl.com" onclick="show_price()" target="_blank">
   Click Here to reveal price
<a>

<script>
   function show_price() {
       document.getElementById('price').style.display = '';
       document.getElementById('price_ad').style.display = 'none';
   }
</script>
```

This way, on click, link disappears, price appears, and popup opens.

Comment: not working...the text from the field price is not displayed in popup or otherwise at all now

Comment: plus i want the pop window to have the code...thts not happening here

Comment: You want a REAL popup, a new window ? or a "popin" a fake popup, styled in CSS, inside the window ? Because I don't get the point of having the price of a product in a separate window...

Comment: And for the price never appearing, I guess you have a problem elsewhere (get_field('price') not working ?) because this code works : http://jsfiddle.net/yEM98/

Comment: yes i was a real pop...spoiler or reveal type u know when u click on it a window comes with the hidden text.

Comment: in the fiddle the click here to reveal text is replaced by the price. instead i want a pop to show the price

Comment: see with the css its giving problem http://jsfiddle.net/yEM98/3/ an extra empty bar come up plus after clicking the price is outside the clickbtn and not inside as it shud be

Comment: Well, I don't know what is the "clickbtn", as you've forgotten the </div> closing tag. Anyway, you've not styled the clickbtn, but only the link inside, so it's perfectly normal.

Comment: And you've also miswritten the </a> closing tag.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you to learn how popups work in javascript. For example : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/yEM98/4/ ...after clicking the black box disappears behind the price how do i get tht to remain

Comment: plus if i have loop showing more than 1 item then on clickingon any click here to reveal ...it reveals only the first ones' price not the book i clicked on http://jsfiddle.net/yEM98/7/

Comment: You have only 1 item in your example. Anyway, you're using html IDs so your problem is normal : you have to use classes if you have several items. You can't have several items having the same ID.

Comment: $post->id grabs the id for each post right i put echo $price outside the span the price fields are echoed correctly, but inside only the first's price is displayed no matter which one u click

Comment: anything plz any tip on how to get it working for each

Comment: I was not speaking of PHP "->id", but HTML id="xxx", which has to be unique.

Comment: i still don't get it...html id will be for css right...css is not the problem now i have the box in background for both...

Comment: my problem now is - when multiple items i get the price using getfield...outside span it displays correctly but when inside it-its displays the price of the last item whichever one u click.

Comment: btw the html id is unique right 'price' and 'price_ad' in this case

Comment: You said you had several items (several prices) don't you ? Then you have id="price" more that once, am I wrong ?

Comment: Anyway, just to be sure : have you understood each bit of the code I've posted ? Or is some of it like chinese for you (or russian if you're chinese!) ?

Comment: i have many items each has a price...for each item i pull the price using the get_field into the variable $price...which i want to display    when the corresponding "click here" is clicked.

Comment: to check i removed the line style="display:none" from the spanid=price and the correct price is displaced...but i can't figure out y with tht bit it reveals only the last enter item's price instead of the corresponding one's

Comment: itsgot to do with onclick getting applied to the reveal the last item instead of the correspoding one

Comment: how do i get it to select id= "price" of the particular "post id"

Comment: Ok, so you have several items, each one has a span with id=price ; so is there only one id named "price" in your entire page ? I let you answer...

Comment: Anyway, if you had only tried to understand my code, you would know that id="price" is not only used for CSS, but also for Javascript.

Comment: i figured tht i have to generate unqiue spanid 'price' for each item and then target tht particular one onclick. but i m unable to ...say the postid is65 then i m trying to get the span id="price65" for it to begenerated dynamically...but can't

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yEM98/14/ onclick doesn'twork in this though i have managedto create different ids for each item

Comment: plz check the check on localhost...output on jsfiddle is coming very different for http://jsfiddle.net/yEM98/14/

Comment: I really think you're missing some basic concepts of Web Programming, like server-side (PHP) VS client-side (HTML/JS/CSS) languages. JsFiddle, as a client-side host, doesn't understand PHP ; and the way you put PHP inside javascript doesn't have any sense. PHP's only role, as a server-side language, is to **generate** a HTML/JS/CSS page. Once the page is on your screen, there is no more PHP - your browser doesn't understand PHP at all.

Comment: ok seeing the code...can u tell me y the click is not longer working

Comment: No I can't, have you thought for yourself ? have you looked at the source code of your page ? is everything ok ?

Comment: i can't figure it out where i m wrong...i donno know javascript

Comment: Well, this is not the place to learn basics of Javascript, there are lots of websites for it... But at least give your code, your generated HTML (somewhere like right click > show source).

Comment: Do you know what is a function in programming ?

Comment: ye i do know what functions is :) http://myproject.byethost7.com/test1.php u can see the code in action here

Comment: Well... it's perfectly working now, at least for your last problem, isn't it ?

Comment: yes guy at another thread helped correct the code ...seems href shudn't be there as u put it